# Adding values to list in nested function

Tags: java, android, list

I'm having trouble getting the values to add to the `userInterests` list.

The function returns an empty list despite the object check proving there are values there. What am I doing wrong?

```
 public List getUserInterests(String id){
    final ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryFindAllInterests = ParseQuery.getQuery("Interests");
    final List<String> userInterests = new ArrayList<>();

    queryFindAllInterests.whereEqualTo("user", id);
    queryFindAllInterests.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(final List<ParseObject> interestList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                  for (ParseObject object : interestList) {
                        userInterests.add(object.getString("interest"));
                        System.out.println("Object check: " + object);
                   }
            } else {
                  Log.d("interest retrieval", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

    System.out.println("User interests: " + userInterests);
    return userInterests;
}
```

On run:

```
I/System.out: User interests: []
I/System.out: Object check: com.parse.ParseObject@132ac47a
I/System.out: Object check: com.parse.ParseObject@216f042b
I/System.out: Object check: com.parse.ParseObject@33cc1088
I/System.out: Object check: com.parse.ParseObject@c1caa21
```

UPDATE:

So I changed the for loop to:

```
for (ParseObject object : interestList) {
                        String interest = object.getString("interest");
                        userInterests.add(interest);
                        System.out.println("Object check: " + interest);
                        }
```

The output displayed the correct strings:

```
  I/System.out: User interests: []
  I/System.out: returned list: []
  I/System.out: Object check: coffee    
  I/System.out: Object check: computers
  I/System.out: Object check: bees
  I/System.out: Object check: table
```

Comment: Printing `object` doesn't mean much, since you aren't adding that to `userInterests`.  You're adding the result of a call to `object.getString("interest")` to your list, which is probably returning `null`.

Comment: I don't know much about android, but it looks to me as if you are adding the object to the list in another thread so maybe you return from the function earlier than that thread finishes.

Comment: can you try this (provided you are getting result)
`userInterests.add(new String(object.getString("interest")));`

Comment: and as @azurefrog said, print the value instead of object itself.

Comment: What exactly does queryFindAllInterests.findInBackground() do? If it does what its name implies, it is just creating another thread that eventually invokes the FindCallback.done() method. But the original thr3ead marches merrily on and invokes the println("User interests...") **before** the done method is called. Your print of the output lines also suggests this - you print out the interests array before it has been filled.

Comment: @FredK Your assumption on what `queryFindAllInterests.findInBackground()` does is correct. What is a viable solution? I tried putting a thread.sleep after the query, but it had no affect. Should I be using some sort of concurrency?